# Expansion of Helmholtz energy

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, ideal-gas, integration

To get an expansion of Helmholtz energy of

a) an ideal gas 
b) a Van der waals gas

we must integrate

$\left ( \frac{\delta A }{\delta V} \right )_{T}=-P$

I saw the solution is :

[image]

Can you explain why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider just part (a).  we use the ideal gas law for $P$, that is
$$-P=-\frac{nRT}{V}$$
and substituting this in for $P$ we get
$$\delta A=-\frac{nRT}{V}\delta V\implies\Delta A=-nRT\int_{V_1}^{V_{2}}\frac{1}{V}dV$$
which gives
$$\Delta A=-nRT(\ln(V_2)-\ln(V_1))=-nRT\ln\left(\frac{V_2}{V_2}\right)$$
I'm not sure where the $n$ went...  It's key we held $T$ constant.
Hope this helps.